# "Upload Failed: No Data" while trying to upload an image

Tags: joomla-3.4, jce, media-manager

I built a new site in Joomla 3.4.5 with JCE editor 2.5.11. When I tried to upload an image in the JCE's image dialog, it failed with `"Upload Failed: No Data"`. Unlike [this case](https://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/support/forum/some-jpg-uploads-did-not-succeed-after-update-to-jce-2-5-9), this error occurs for every image, not just some. I checked in the [source code (row 823)](https://github.com/widgetfactory/jce/blob/master/components/com_jce/editor/libraries/classes/browser.php) that JCE thinks the image file is empty, so it probably fails before reaching the JCE file check.

So I tried to upload the image in backend (media manager). In complains about files being too big instead. The limit is set to 10MB and I tested this with image files of several tens or hundreds kB, so there must be some bug. But how to correct/ workaround it?

EDIT: after upgrade to Joomla 3.4.8 and JCE to 2.5.14, the error message in the frontend changed to `[object Object]`. The error in the backend is still the same.

Comment: Why would you build a Joomla site with an old (and vulnerable) version? First, start with the latest Joomla and JCE Editor. Review  System Information / Permissions.

Comment: @Anibal: I installed it with 3.4.3 several months ago and didn't have time for testing a backup since then, so I was afraid to upgrade. Now I checked again and I did some upgrade, it's 3.4.5 now. Joomla 3.4.5 and JCE 2.5.11 isn't so old, is it? I take it as an encouragement to backup and upgrade my site though, even if connection with this bug was unlikely.

Comment: @PavelV. There have been security vulnerabilities that are easily exploitable with recent versions of Joomla. You should update to 3.4.8, which fixes them all

Comment: @Lodder: my site is now more secure, but the problem in question changed only cosmetically. See my edit.

Comment: Are you seeing a javascript error in the browser Error Console when attempting an upload? Have you clear you cache browser?

Comment: @PavelV. Please also update JCE Editor to the latest version (2.5.14) as the issue you have **may** have been fixed.

Comment: @Lodder: I should have taken a coffee - I updated JCE as well and didn't tell you about. I'll return to it when I'll be able to concentrate. Pierre-AndréVullioud, thanks for the tip, I'll inspect it in Firebug more thoroughly; the first short run showed nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Lodder and others were right that the answer was to keep site up to date and be patient. The error was corrected in JCE 2.5.15.

Comment: Glad it was as simple as a quick update :)